# Why the color difference happening between the original video and the video played with GVRVideoView?

Tags: ios, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I am developing a small application for education. But there is a difference between original video colors and played video with GVRVideoView.

You can see the difference below,

[image: Video compare image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The problem happening from video color matrix. And i changed color matrix with ffmpeg commands. If your video color matrix BT.709 then vrsdk can't render correctly.

I used below ffmpeg command and after that everything is fine;

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -b:v 20M -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a copy output.mp4
```